# Deciding which referenced assemblies should be added to frameworkAssemblies

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

I'm currently working on packing the libraries we work with in my team, and I got stuck when it comes to `frameworkAssemblies` list in the nuspec file.

I understand that frameworkAssemblies is only for assemblies installed on GAC. The problems is that a project (let's call it project A) could use many GAC assemblies, but once an other project (project B) references project A it probably won't need each and every project A's references and sometimes none of them, yet some other times it will require referencing some of them.

So the question is how do I decide which references of my class library project should be added as `frameworkAssemblies` and which should not?

As I see it, it's not reasonable to go through each and every class of my project and check what references should someone add when using this class and therefore, I'm left with two possibilities, which none is optimal: (a) Adding each and every reference as frameworkAssembly or (b) Add none.